# How to compute this series

Tags: power-series

I have to compute this series :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^{2k}$$

First, I have $$|x|<1$$
but then I don't know how to begin ...

Comment: $x^{2k}=(x^2)^k$. Now, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: We usually say serie**s**, even when its just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that this is a power series with radius of convergence $r=1$. Thus, for $\lvert y\rvert < r$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)y^k = \frac{d}{dy} \sum_{k=0}^\infty y^{k+1} = \frac{d}{dy} \sum_{k=1}^\infty y^{k}
$$
and 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty y^{k} = \frac{y}{1-y}.
$$
Now, you can compute the derivative of $\frac{y}{1-y}$, and evaluate it on $x^2$ (which has $x^2 < r$ indeed).

Comment: Thanks ! But is the first equality trivial ? I mean getting $d/dy$ out of the sum ? Or is it because the series converge for $|y|<1$ ?

Comment: It is not trivial -- it holds because power series (in particular) uniformly converge in their disk of convergence.